# VB2010 Setting logarithmic scale intervals

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, charts, intervals

I'm developing a financial application in which I need to display data in a chart with a logarithmic scale on the Y axis. Everything works fine except for the intervals. With the following:

```
chart.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.IsLogarithmic = True
chart.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.LogarithmBase = 10
chart.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Interval = 1

chart.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Minimum = CalcMinYVal(minYVal)
```

I get the CalcMinYVal multiplied by 10^0,10^1,10^2,10^3 and so on for the Y-axis values.

I would like to have the Y axis values increased by 1. How can I have the interval be REALLY 1?

Comment: If the values of the Y axis would increase by 1, would it still remain a logarithmic scale? or it would become a linear?

Comment: I hope this shows exactly what I mean. I just want to show values in between. I know It is not to scale, but just to graphically show what I want.    !(http://s3.postimg.org/3qxfutn3n/log_example.png).

Comment: To keep it simple, I don't represent the CalcMinYval in the Logarithmic (what I get) graph, but the Base is 10 and the Interval 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable the `MinorGrid` property

`chart.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.MinorGrid = True`

to show the horizontal lines in between the powers of 10 like shown below.

[image]

But there is a limitation in showing the value for each subdivision. They can only appear in fixed intervals by using the `Interval` property of the `LabelStyle`.

For example to show 10 subdivisions, you can set:

`Chart.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.LabelStyle.Interval = 0.1`

[image]

The number of the horizontal lines of the `MinorGrid` can be controlled by using its `Interval` propery:

```
Chart.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.MinorGrid.Interval = 1
```

and the values of the labels can be rounded by using the `format` property:

```
Chart.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "{0.0}"
```